# Setting default timezone in UNIX Timestamp

Tags: php

So, here is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
```

I want to set the default timezone for this, the above won't work, any help?

Comment: `time` will always output seconds since the unix epoch (UTC) - the timezone is only effective if/when you format the time with `date`.

Comment: Do this work? echo date_default_timezone_get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time()` - Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Please read - http://www.php.net/time

Answer (score 0):

`time()` functoin returns a Unix timestamp (number of seconds from January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) which is indipendent of time zone. Time zone setting influences the `date()` function.

Answer (score 0):

time() Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix epoch.
You should use [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)